# Not able to kill previous counter when countdown is placed in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a simple countdown as such below which is working fine  except when it is placed in the loop. During looping both previous and new counter remains working .I want to kill the previous counter and start with a new, which i am not able to achieve. Can anybody help on this please

```
function triggerEvery60Sec(){

    var myCounter = new Countdown({  
        seconds:5,  // number of seconds to count down
        onUpdateStatus: function(sec){console.log(sec);}, // callback for each second
        onCounterEnd: function(){ alert('counter ended!');} // final action
    });

    myCounter.start();
}


function Countdown(options) {
    var timer,
    instance = this,
    seconds = options.seconds || 10,
    updateStatus = options.onUpdateStatus || function () {},
    counterEnd = options.onCounterEnd || function () {};

    function decrementCounter() {
        updateStatus(seconds);
        if (seconds === 0) {
            counterEnd();
            instance.stop();
        }
        seconds--;
    }

    this.start = function () {
        clearInterval(timer);
        timer = 0;
        seconds = options.seconds;
        timer = setInterval(decrementCounter, 1000);
    };

    this.stop = function () {
        clearInterval(timer);
    };
}
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle for it

Comment: how is `triggerEvery60Sec` used

Comment: Hi, Thanks for response. I have pasted the jsfiddle link. u can try it.  step1: click on button set60SecTimer and then press stop60SecTimer. Again go back to set60SecTimer click. Then the div tag having content "This page updates automatically every minute. The next update will be in 18 seconds." should reset and start from begining.  http://jsfiddle.net/GELXy/1/ Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of declare your variable in the loop, maybe should you declare it before, and manipulate it during your loop.

```
var myCounter = null;

function triggerEvery60Sec(){

    myCounter = new Countdown({  
    seconds:5,  // number of seconds to count down
    onUpdateStatus: function(sec){console.log(sec);}, // callback for each second
    onCounterEnd: function(){ alert('counter ended!');} // final action
});

myCounter.start();
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for response. I have pasted my problem in the jsfiddle link. u can try it and help me with this. step1: click on button set60SecTimer and then press stop60SecTimer. Again go back to set60SecTimer click. Then the div tag having content "This page updates automatically every minute. The next update will be in 18 seconds." should reset and start from begining. http://jsfiddle.net/GELXy/1/ Thanks in advance

Comment: As you can see here : http://jsfiddle.net/GELXy/2/ , when you click on button1, the timer start again at 60.